# How do I bind to a translatetransform

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have added a custom Drag Behaviour to a TextBlock on a grid

The XAML

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"  >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <flowfieldVisualiser:DragBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>        
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

The code for the Behavior

```
public class DragBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
    {
        private Point _elementStartPosition;
        private Point _mouseStartPosition;
        private readonly TranslateTransform _transform = new TranslateTransform();

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.RenderTransform = _transform;
            AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove += AssociatedObject_MouseMove;
        }

        void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var parent = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            _elementStartPosition = AssociatedObject.TranslatePoint(new Point(), parent);

            var vector = e.GetPosition(parent) - _elementStartPosition;
            _mouseStartPosition = new Point(vector.X, vector.Y);

            AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();
        }

        void AssociatedObject_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var parent = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            _elementStartPosition = AssociatedObject.TranslatePoint(new Point(), parent);
            var diff = e.GetPosition(parent) - _mouseStartPosition;
            if (AssociatedObject.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                _transform.X = diff.X;
                _transform.Y = diff.Y;
            }
        }

        void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
    }
```

This works well and I can drag the text box around. The problem is, I need to know what the new values are in my datacontext. How do I get the TranslateTransform x and y bound to x and y properties of my data Context?

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample

```cs
    Binding bindingX = new Binding("DataContext.X");
    bindingX.Source = AssociatedObject;
    bindingX.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(_transform, TranslateTransform.XProperty, bindingX);
```

assuming the `DataContext` the view model is having a property named `X` above code will set a binding on _transform  for `TranslateTransform.XProperty`, which will push the value to the source binding which is the AssociatedObject's DataContext.X. hence pushing values to VM's property.

you may also need to set the same for Y property.

for information `UIElement` does not have DataContext, so unless the AssociatedObject is of type `FrameworkElement` above may not work as expected.

you may also change the same to `Behavior<FrameworkElement>` for better reliability

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how would I do that via xaml? It feels wrong to add binding in the custom Behavior, I do not want to bind on some other controls I still want to move.

Comment: @JohnPetrak, since the source (tansform) which is to be bounded is not in xaml, it may not be possible to do it in xaml. however you can use another attached behavior to bind the same. BTW there is nothing wrong in binding in behavior, but having separate behavior may help you separate the code.